# can't get appengine python sample for flask or django to work

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have downloaded the appengine samples.

When I enter directory python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/django and install it on my appengine project, and then look at the project web page, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 358, in __getattr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 294, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 165, in initialize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~forcediagnosticsclinic/20180707t052537.410964682053028174/appengine_config.py", line 18, in <module>
    vendor.add('lib')
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/vendor/__init__.py", line 44, in add
    'No such virtualenv or site directory' % path)
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

What is going on?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial @Alex provided?: 
   https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Answer (score 0):

You app config refers to folder called `lib` and this folder is missing or you forgot to copy it properly. Try to get the same project working on your local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Lenik is right. Specifically, it looks like you didn't do this step in the tutorial:

`pip install -r requirements-vendor.txt -t lib/`

https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#run_the_app_on_your_local_computer